# Spring ResponseBodyEmitter and SseEmitter stuck initialising and accumulating earlySendAttempts

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, server-sent-events

I have a Spring Boot (v2.0.3) web application serving SSE and encountered an issue where sometimes the SseEmitter instance is stuck "initialising" and never gets a `ResponseBodyEmitter.Handler` configured through `ResponseBodyEmitter.initialize(..)`. With the SseEmitter in this state, I end up having two issues:

- The application is not aware that the client has terminated the connection and thus keeps writing to the SseEmitter instance causing the `ResponseBodyEmitter.earlySendAttempts` to keep growing. (Note: the application also sends keepalive messages to the client in order to check for client disconnections which work under normal circumstances).
- The SseEmitter timeout (currently set to 30 minutes) is not triggered causing the `ResponseBodyEmitter.earlySendAttempts` to keep growing indefinitely.

This issue does not happen often, but when it does the application eventually runs out of memory. I have tried to replicate the issue and have failed to do so consistently, however, I have managed to notice the following in my attempts:

- It occurs when the client abruptly terminates the connection prior to the handling of the request i.e. before the HTTP response headers are sent back. This does not happen to every abruptly terminated request.
- It occurs more often when the request is the first request after application startup.

In an attempt to understand what is going on, I enabled TRACE logs and have discovered the following:

1. When the issue occurs the logs show a `ClientAbortException` which does not come up when the application behaves correctly.

   ```
    org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:321)
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:284)
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:541)
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:312)
       at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
       at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
       at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:159)
       at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse.flush(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:90)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.handleReturnValue(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:162)
       at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158)
       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126)
       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at com.foobar.AuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(AuthenticationFilter.java:64)
       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
       at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
       at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
       at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
       at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
       at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1276)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:670)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flushBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:607)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flush(SocketWrapperBase.java:597)
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:646)
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.flush(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:169)
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:252)
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.flush(Http11Processor.java:1564)
       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:352)
       at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:173)
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:317)
       ... 93 common frames omitted
   ```
2. On the other hand, when the issue does not occur the logs show the following.

   ```
   org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl$DebugException: null
       at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.logDebug(AsyncContextImpl.java:486)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.<init>(AsyncContextImpl.java:85)
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:1676)
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.startAsync(RequestFacade.java:1038)
       at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:398)
       at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:398)
       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.startAsync(HttpServlet3RequestFactory.java:200)
       at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.startAsync(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:122)
       at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.startAsyncProcessing(WebAsyncManager.java:432)
       at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.startDeferredResultProcessing(WebAsyncManager.java:413)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.handleReturnValue(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:166)
       at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158)
       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126)
       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at at com.foobar.AuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(AuthenticationFilter.java:64)
       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   ```

I am not sure how the handle this situation going forward. Is there anything I might have misconfigured on my end? Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2):

We have the same problem on a customer machine as you has described in your post. Sometimes the ResponseBodyEmitter is initialized without passing a handler to the initalize method, so when a message shall be sent the earlySendAttempts HashSet will be stuffed with the message.

This behavior causes in a memoryleak on the customer machine, while the HashSet is growing up to to a size of at least 10gb.

Do you have already found a solution for this problem?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Hi @peeage, sorry for the late reply. I didn't get any replies about the issue but have a workaround which avoids the memory leak you're experiencing. I've extended SseEmitter and added an isInitalised() method which uses reflection to check whether the handler field in the underlying ResponseBodyEmitter is null. On sending data I check whether the custom sseEmitter instance isInitialised() and if not I clean up.